# Заменить только одно значение массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив формата

```
    $array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Надо получить такой же массив, но с одним замененным значением, типа

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "123",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Как такое устроить?

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: я тупой, и не смог нормально выгуг "лить это дело. час уже сижу гуглю. видимо хз как сформулировать, или что... @Эдуард

Comment: Посмотрите информацию о массивах и обращение по ключу. Посидите день, а не час. Можете хотя бы словесно оформить то, что хотите, чтобы было в коде. И только после этого понимания искать информацию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский долгое отсутствие на СО, однако )

Comment: @teran я тоже хотел об этом написать 

Comment: @teran ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array['foo'] = '123';
```

Собственно и всё.

Comment: Спасибо. Я  не на столько разбираюсь на сколько хотелось бы, и почему-то не смог выгуглить) спасибо!)